# Библиотека для работы с PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, signature

Требуется библиотека для создание pdf документа с электронной цифровой подписью для .NET. Библиотека должна быть бесплатной.

Comment: Гугл что говорит на эту тему?

Comment: я нашел только iTextSharp.

Comment: Чем он не устроил?

Comment: Хотелось чтоб работа с ЭЦП поддерживалась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует open-source библиотека [iTextSharp](https://itextpdf.com/en). Вот [ссылка](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14488/E-signing-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp), где объясняется, как подписать pdf-документ с помощью электронно-цифровой подписи. Если вы не хотите использовать сторонние библиотеки, вы можете реализовать это сами, но задача будет не самой простой (в таком случаем можно начать с просмотра [спецификации PDF](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))

Ответ переведен с английского SO. Оригинал находится [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379033/6468198)

Comment: Статья старая. Было бы неплохо, если кто-то найдет более актуальную информацию